# How to use withLatestFrom with a promise?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

Why isn't it possible to convert a `promise` to an `observable` and then use it with `withLatestFrom`. It's not clear to me, why this doesn't resolve.

```
of('')
  .pipe(
    withLatestFrom(from(myPromise)),
    map((res) => {
      console.log('does not resolve', res);
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: It is possible to use `withLatestFrom` with promises. You'll need to make a reproducible demo because it's impossible to give any advice like this.

Comment: @martin i provided a demo, i have a promise and i'll want to use the resolved value inside the map function using withLatestFrom so i can access both values (value from source observable and value from the promise). I'm not shure what you are asking for?

Comment: This question is +2 years old, but I think `lastValueFrom` and `firstValueFrom` are now available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WithLatestFrom` emits only when its source Observable emits, since `of('')` emits before the source to withLatestFrom, your `withLatestFrom` is never triggered.

The following code will not work:

```
of('1 + 1')
  .pipe(
    withLatestFrom(new Promise(x => x("== 2"))),
    map(([res1,res2]) => console.log(res1, res2))
  )
  .subscribe();
```

but this will:

```
of('1 + 1')
  .pipe(
    delay(100), // <= delay source execution
    withLatestFrom(new Promise(x => x("== 2"))),
    map(([res1,res2]) => console.log(res1, res2))
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: Any advice how i can get the value of the source observable and the value of the promise in a map function without using an ugly hack as the delay.

Comment: You can force `of('')` to run asynchronously using `observeOn(asyncScheduler)` alternatively consider using `combineLatest` operator

Comment: see https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/scheduler

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour for `withLatestFrom`. The source observable completes synchronously before the promise resolves (asynchronously). `withLatestFrom` only emits once both observables have emitted at least once and then only emits when the source observable emits.

In your case, the source observable is complete before the promise resolves.

```
of('').pipe(
  delay(100),
  withLatestFrom(from(myPromise)),
  tap(res =>
    console.log('should resolve', res)
  )
).subscribe();
```

#### Update #1 : solutions without `delay`

If both source observables emit once and complete, then `forkJoin` is best

```
forkJoin({
  addition: of(1 + 1),
  promise: from(myPromise)
}).pipe(
  map(({addition, promise}) => {return /* something */})
)
```

`combineLatest` is similar to `forkJoin` but it works better with long-lived streams that keep emitting values. It waits for its inner streams to all start emitting and then emits all their latest values.

```
combineLatest(
  of(1 + 1),
  from(myPromise)
).pipe(
  map(([addition, promise]) => {return /* something */})
)
```

Or, if you want to use `withLatestFrom` and your comfortable with the timing constraints.

```
from(myPromise).pipe(
  withLatestFrom(of(1+1)),
  map(([promise, addition]) => {return /* something */})
)
```

should work.

Comment: @mnewmedia added some examples of how to do this without using `delay`

Answer (score 0):

As Rafi pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65111772/6813271), this fails because the promise will only resolves too late.

Another solution to the ones mentioned in his answer is to use one of the higher-order mapping operators (`switchMap`, `mergeMap`, `concatMap` or `exhaustMap`) to add the value the promise resolves to to the observable pipe:

```
const promise = Promise.resolve('promise');
of('observable')
  .pipe(switchMap(async (value) => [value, await promise]))
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Alternatively, which is the simplest solution by far as long as the promise value is only needed at the end of the chain, is to convert the subscriber into an async function (which may require a linter rule complaining about the mismatch between `void` and `Promise<void>` to be disabled, as the returned promise will now be ignored):

```
const promise = Promise.resolve('promise');
of('observable').subscribe(async (observableValue) => {
  const promiseValue = await promise;
  console.log(observableValue, promiseValue);
});
```